# Windows port/implementation for GNU Pth (Gnu Portable Threads)

Tags: c, multithreading, gnu

I have inherited a pure C project that uses GNU Pth ( http://www.gnu.org/software/pth/ ) and I was hoping that there was a Windows port/implementation so I wouldn't have to stick a whole bunch (more) conditionals into my code.

I know I am being hopeful, but is there anything that provides the exact same function signatures and functionality?

If not, is there any good pure C cross-platform multi-threading library (even if it is different than Pth)?

**Edit:**

I just found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Portable_Runtime#Threads and it sounds like that might be the way to go. Opinions on NSPR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pthread on windows http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/ which is quite stable and the performances are good. This is what we use to port our threaded unix code to windows.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this but since it hadn't been updated in awhile was quite leery of it.

Comment: as a follow up, I have had 0 problems using pthreads-win32 on windows and pthreads on *nix/mac